# Creating an action link in a Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In one of my controller actions, I'm generating some XML. One of the attributes in that XML is an `href` to another controller and action, with some parameters. The XML should look something like this:

```
<projects>
  <project id="42" name="Project X", href="/projects/42"/>
  <!-- etc. -->
</projects>
```

I don't mind if the URL is relative or absolute, but my question is this: how do I generate the URL in the controller code, in a type-safe way?

In other words, how do I do what `HtmlHelper.ActionLink` does, but from a controller?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found it by using Reflector:

```
string href = Url.Action("DetailsAsXml", new { projectId = item.Id });
```

Comment: Still valid in ASP.NET Core 1.0.x. `Url` is a property of abstract class `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` which implements `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper`.